# Formula of line segment joining 2 points

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry

I've got a question that is probably a bit simple but I can't figure it out sadly.

I read in my textbook that, given 2 points $x,y$ of a set, the line segment that connects these 2 points can be described by the expression 
$$\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y, \lambda \in [0,1]$$

Is there some kind of derivation for this particular formula you can show me? Thanks a lot.

P.S. I don't really know what tags to add so if these two are incorrect please edit freely.

Comment: To be precise, in a vector space (such as $\Bbb R^n$), the formula above describes the line *segment* connecting $x$ and $y$.  For the formula to make sense, you need to know how to multiply a point by an element of $\Bbb R$ and you need to know how to add two points in the space, which is why you need a vector space structure (or something like it).

Comment: Yeah my mistake, it is a line segment that has $x,y$ as it's two end points. What you're saying is right, I just cant figure out the proof behind this. The rest of the details are important but not my problem in this particular question.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a proof.  That formula may be the definition of the segment connecting the two points.  If that's not it, what definition of a line segment are you using?

Comment: Can't say I have an alternative. Just trying to grasp the reasoning behind this one hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite it as $y + \lambda(x-y)$ and recognize $y$ as the 'anchor point' and $(x-y)$ as the vector pointing from $y$ to $x$.
Does this visualization help?

As $\lambda$ varies from $0$ to $1$, one moves from the 'anchor' $y$ along $(x-y)$ until $x$.

Comment: The way I visualize this is with vectors. Is that correct? So for each $\lambda$ (they are infinite ofcourse) we have $y$ which is a vector from zero to this point and I add to it another vector, a portion $(\lambda)$ of the vector $x-y$. The result of this vector addition is another vector which gives me the position of a point in between $x$ and $y$. Thus for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$ we get all the points in between them? Probably overthinking this.

Comment: I think that's okay. Sometimes it's best to think of vectors as points and sometimes as arrows. In this case, I think it's helpful to think of $y$ as a point and of $(x-y)$ as an arrow.

Comment: That's actually a good idea. Like having 2 points $A,B$ and $AB$ the vector joining them. We start for $A$ and move along this vector a $\lambda$ portion of it. Hmm. But since the lamdas are infinite isnt this expression I posted in my original post giving all the infinite segments in between A,B?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. There are infinitely many values that $\lambda$ can assume, but each value is finite (between $0$ and $1$).

Comment: What I meant is that for each $\lambda$ you get a different line segment so how can this expression represent just 1 line segment connecting x with y? But yeah I m not even sure what Im saying, sorry. Your question helped me so Ill accept it but I still need to think this through. Thanks :)

Comment: For each $\lambda$ you get a different *point* on the line segment. You don't get different segments for each $\lambda$.

Comment: So this expression represents all the points in between and including $x,y$ AND also the line segment that connects them? Sorry if im asking silly questions

Comment: Isn't the line segment that connects them precisely the point in between them including $x$ and $y$?

Comment: If by that you mean that the infinite points in between x and y create a line segment that connects them then yeah I can understand what you're saying